# Can I run unreal 5.3 with xcode 15 on Mac Sonoma

Tags: xcode, unreal-engine5, macos-sonoma, unreal

I'm trying to run `Unreal 5.3` and `Unreal 5.1` projects with C++ on the latest `Mac Sonoma` along with `Xcode 15`. Keep getting an error of `"Platform Mac is not a valid platform to build. Check that the SDK is installed properly."`

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I'm trying to figure out if it’s safe to upgrade from Ventura to Sonoma.

Comment: Yes - see below my answer - all is working - Sonoma seems to be playing great

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of writing - it's not possible.
Instead Download and install `Xcode 14`.

When trying to install you will get an error not supported - use later version.
It will deny it on `Sonoma`, but you can right click and open content. Then open
/Applications/Xcode_14.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Than open xcode 14, navigate to settings and choose the built tools for xcode 14 [image]

Than try again to open an unreal project with C++ and it will work